# Using a parameter without name

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I'm working on a project my professor gave me.  One of the functions that I have to implement uses a parameter passed in as such.  Normally I am used to using parameters with variables.

Instruction as to what the function is supposed to do:

`binMinHeap<Type>::binMinHeap(int capacity)`-default constructor that sets
`this->capacity` with the parameter passed in, sets the size accordingly, and allocates an array to heapArray

He also provides the piece below and I am not supposed to edit any of the functions or parameters.

```
class binMinHeap
{
   public:
   binMinHeap(int = 10);
   ...
}
```

As an example, normally if the function was given such as `binMinHead(int capactity)`, I would understand to do something such as

```
 binMinHeap(int capacity= 10){
      something = capacity;
      ...
 }
```

but how do I access the parameter of just "int=10"?

Comment: it's just a declaration, you don't need variable names there. when you implement the function, you can choose whatever variable name you want and use it. So long as you don't change the declaration (variable type or default value, which you should omit completely as far as i remember), your code will compile fine.

Comment: this may be dumb... but do I just put "this->capacity"?

Comment: no, you just implement `binMinHeap(int capacity)`!

Comment: the name of a parameter can be omitted in a declaration and/or definition, but of course in that case that parameter cannot access if missing in definition. Warning default value cannot be specified in the definition out of the class definition so `binMinHeap(int capacity= 10){...}` must be `binMinHeap::binMinHeap(int capacity){..}`

Comment: class binMinHeap
{
   public:
   binMinHeap(int = 10);
   ...
}                                                                                                        Since he said do not change the function and he gave it to me in that way is there a way to use the int=10 without  doing 
binMinHeap(int capacity) cus thats what I would have done too lol

Comment: @101001 the name of the parameters is only important in the definition because if you use them this is in the definition

Comment: you don't seem to get it. you were told not to change the declaration. you can still implement the function however way you like. please take some time to learn the difference between **declaration** and **implementation**.

Comment: will the declaration of 10 still be able to be used outside of the declaration? or do I have to reimplement that when I'm creating the actual function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how do I access the parameter of just "int=10"?

`int = 10` declares an [unnamed parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list) with type `int` and default argument `10`. If you want to use it, you need to specify the name for it. In the declaration the name is not used and not required, you can specify the name in the definition.

```
class binMinHeap
{
   public:
   binMinHeap(int = 10); // declaration
};

// definition
binMinHeap::binMinHeap(int capacity) {
   something = capacity;
   ...
}
```

Comment: thats where I'm confused because he said do not change the functions and thats function he gave me

Comment: @101001 I suppose he mean don't change the declaration and you need to give the definition.

Comment: OHH i think i get it now, its okay to change it outside of the declaration!!! lol okay maybe I was overthinking it